# Vscode unauthorized compiling the code unde win10 os

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, cordova-win10

I'm currently using vscode under win10 os running my angular 8 project. When I use the angular cli command ng serve --open to start the project, at the first like half an hour or one hour, it runs normally, but after that, the vscode will automatically compile the code without any changes saving. Sometimes it will run only once or twice, will take like around 10 sec, but sometimes, it get insane, it will compile the code like 7 times, and every time it will take a really long time like around 10 sec.

Following is snapshot when it automatically compile the code unauthorized:

Snapshot:

```
Date: 2019-08-31T12:33:16.407Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 11348ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /profile-em/24/resume

Date: 2019-08-31T12:33:28.507Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 11498ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js

Date: 2019-08-31T12:33:38.244Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 9239ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /scripts.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js.map
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js.map

Date: 2019-08-31T12:33:48.079Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 8827ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/fonts/REX_icons.ttf?mffa75
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/fonts/Linotype-ITC-Charter-Com-Black-Italic.ttf
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/images/pwc-logo.png
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/images/Notification_Icon_Bell.png
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/images/photos/default.png

Date: 2019-08-31T12:34:08.586Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 19545ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /profile-em/24/resume
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/i18n/en.json
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /scripts.js.map
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /app-routes-home-home-module.js

Date: 2019-08-31T12:34:17.381Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 8148ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /assets/i18n/en.json
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js

Date: 2019-08-31T12:34:31.304Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 13302ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /scripts.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js.map
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js.map

Date: 2019-08-31T12:34:37.792Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 5986ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2019-08-31T12:35:25.485Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 7138ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /profile-em/24/resume

Date: 2019-08-31T12:35:33.725Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 7794ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js

Date: 2019-08-31T12:35:41.982Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 7815ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /runtime.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /polyfills.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /scripts.js
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /styles.js.map
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /vendor.js.map
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js.map

Date: 2019-08-31T12:35:49.144Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 6470ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2019-08-31T12:35:58.023Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 8211ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
95% emitting CopyPlugini ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /main.js.map

Date: 2019-08-31T12:36:26.231Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 8046ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...

Date: 2019-08-31T12:36:45.065Z - Hash: fa144bd4f6e3525c72e3
40 unchanged chunks

Time: 18284ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

`

Comment: Make sure that you don't have an out-of-band process that update the files in the application directory

Comment: @ToanNguyen, I'm sorry what do you mean out-of-band process, would you mind give a example? I have no idea what kind of things will be a out-of band process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean that make sure there is no other application trying to change the code outside vs code. One way is to copy the folder to another location to see if things happen again

Comment: @ToanNguyen, thanks Toan, will try to move to a new location.